# How Jasmine handles errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, jasmine

I can't get jasmine testing working smoothly on nodejs. What I mean is that there are situations when the test just stops in the middle of the run, does not notify anything, but silently fails in error. One example I got a few moments ago is this:

In the validater.validateIDs. There is a callback "isOkFunc" that get sent to another modules function to a custom mongoose.find-function

```
validateIDs = function (data, dbFunc) {
        data = data || selfData;

        var
            isOkFunc = (function () {
                var ret = {};
                ret.thisData = void 0;

                ret.setData = function (data) {
                    ret.thisData = (data === undefined) ? true : data;
                };
                return ret;
            })(),
            findData = {
                playerID: data.playerID,
                gameID: data.gameID,
                turnID: data.turnID,
                objectID: data.objectID
            };

        dbFunc.find(findData, isOkFunc.setData);
        return isOkFunc.thisData;
    };
```

The callback get called in the custom find-function:

```
this.find = function (data, cb) {
    models.Order.find(data,function (err, orders) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error in getting orders");
            cb(void 0);
        } else {
            console.log(orders);
            cb(orders);
        }
    });
};
```

Now since I forgot to point the thisData to ret.thisData, it errored, since the variable did not exist. But the problem is that jasmine doesn't notify anything about this, it just silently fails and stops execution. How should this be done for better debugging? Or more like how it should be for ANY realistic debugging?

The actual part in spec-file that caused the problem was this:

```
isOk = validater.validateIDs(data, orderReceive);
```

After stripping few unrelated descibe-sections, here is the whole spec-file:

```
"use strict";
/* This is for making jasmine testing work in windows with netbeans. If this 
 * causes trouble for you, then try to find a better solution. I need this in 
 * windows enviroment */
if(process.platform.match(/^win/)) {
    require("jasmine-node");
};

var uuid = require('node-uuid'),
    orders = require("../../databases/modules/orders.js"),
    orderReceive = orders.ordersAtDatabase("../testDB"),
    data, UUID = uuid.v4();;

/* Counts the amount of finished-class received. When it reaches given point. 
 * Executes all functions. This is supposed to be executed last to remove database entries
 * 
 * Without this we can not test the database ID validation fully, since we need 
 * to have data in database for this */
var toExecuteLast = (function toExecuteLast() {
    var funcs = [], ret = {}, i,
        count = 0,
        max = 5;

    ret.add = function(func) {
        funcs.push(func);
    };
    ret.finished = function() {
        count++;
    };
    ret.do = function() {
        console.log("gogogo");
        if(count >= max) {
            console.log("gogogo2222");
            for(i = 0; i < funcs.length; i++) {
                funcs[i]();
            }
            clearInterval(toExecuteLast.do);
        }
    };

    return ret;
})();

beforeEach(function() {
    data = 
        {
            "playerID": 1,
            "gameID": 1,
            "turnID": 1,
            "objectID": UUID,
            "type": "unit",
            "action": "move",
            "exec": {
                "x": 10,
                "y": 10
            }
        };
});

describe("Testing data validation from data, that would come from frontend", function() {
    var validater;

    validater = orders.orderValidation();

    describe(". User is sending fishy data: ", function(){   
        it(". Test that everything works fine", function() {
            expect(helper).not.toThrow();
        });
        it(". Something fishy with playerID", function() {
            data.playerID = "kjdf ss";
            expect(helper).toThrow(new Error("playerID was not an integer"));
            data.playerID = 12322.33;
            expect(helper).toThrow();
        });
        it(". Something fishy with gameID", function() {
            data.gameID = "kjfkj";
            expect(helper).toThrow(new Error("gameID was not an integer"));
        });
        it(". Something fishy with turnID", function() {
            data.turnID = "| rm -r";
            expect(helper).toThrow(new Error("turnID was not an integer"));
        });
        it(". Something fishy with objectID", function() {
            data.objectID = "| rm -r";
            expect(helper).toThrow(new Error("objectID was not an UUIDv4"));
        });
        it(". Something fishy with type", function() {
            data.type = "| rm -r";
            expect(helper).toThrow();
        });
        it(". Something fishy with action", function() {
            data.action = "| rm -r";
            expect(helper).toThrow(new Error("Action contains illegal character only a-z,A-Z,0-9,_ are allowed"));
        });
        it(". Something fishy with exec", function() {
            data.exec = "| rm -r";
            expect(helper).toThrow(new Error("Action was move, but exec.x was not an integer"));
        });
        toExecuteLast.finished();
    });

    describe(". Do a database check if the IDs that are given (player, game, turn, object) are correct? ", function(){
        /* Remeber that the playerID is fetched from inner data / cookies / auth
         * so it is supposed to be correct. We need it to be correct in the 
         * database too, so we can test the game, turn and object ID validations */
        it(". Everything ok with ID validation?", function() {
            var isOk;

            isOk = validater.validateIDs(data, orderReceive);

            waitsFor(function() {
                return isOk !== 'undefined' ? true : false;
            });

            runs(function() {
                expect(isOk).not.toBeTruthy();
                isOk = false;

                data.gameID = 10;
                isOk = validater.validateIDs(data, orderReceive);

                waitsFor(function() {
                    return (isOk !== 'undefined') ? true : false;
                }, "", 1000);

                runs(function() {
                    // THIS doesn't seem to work, why?
                    expect(true).toBeTruthy();
                    toExecuteLast.finished();
                });
            });
        });

        toExecuteLast.finished();
    });
    function helper() {
        validater.validateRequest(data);
    }
});

setInterval(toExecuteLast.do, 400);
orderReceive.showAll();
//orderReceive.removeAll();
```

Comment: Please, post your spec file.

Comment: @Krasimir I edited the post and added more code there. I don't actually have a clue what kinda effect "use strict" has in node, but out of testing it I added it there too, if that was causing the silent errors, but nothing happened.

Comment: Basically the thing is that, I might have a simple problem in the code, like mis-writing a command / code and normally that shows up clearly with errors. In this case that - more than once - didn't happen. It just silently errored and I got it sometimes diplayed by running it directly through node, instead of jasmine. So actually could be a problem with jasmine-node also, though I suspect the problem is in the way I write the code